# Image viewer supporting tiled gallery from multiple folders

Tags: image-viewers

I am looking for an image viewer which offers all of the following features.

- Tiled image gallery
- Images from multiple directories
- Possible to delete the selected image from the file system

Which image viewer would you recommend?

It is to review thousands of files kept among hundreds of directories.
If the viewer supports recursive image loading, it should suffice. (there is one root directory, and it contains sub directories and image files only.)
It is ideal to view around 50 to 100 images at once.
Unnecessary files should go to the trash bin via an easy operation.
It is nice if one can check multiple images in the gallery and at the end issue the command to trash them.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've found so far is Gwenview. It shows a tiled gallery with folders and a few thumbnails of the pictures within each folder.